# Find values in a JSON string using VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net

I’m a novice and am struggling to work out how to use the Newtonsoft JSON methods to pull out of this JSON string what I’m after with VB.Net.
The first thing to note is that the JSON is in two parts, the Total and then the results.

> "{""total"":9,""results"":[{""id"":1334,""description"":""Fiat"",""type"":0},{""id"":1331,""description"":""Ford"",""type"":0},{""id"":1330,""description"":""Nissan"",""type"":0},{""id"":1335,""description"":""Project
> Alpha"",""type"":0},{""id"":1336,""description"":""Project
> Beta"",""type"":0},{""id"":1337,""description"":""Project
> Gamma"",""type"":0},{""id"":1333,""description"":""Tesla"",""type"":0},{""id"":1332,""description"":""Toyota"",""type"":0},{""id"":1329,""description"":""Volkswagen"",""type"":0}]}"

What I want to do is search the JSON for a particular description and get back the ID. For example if I searched for “Toyota” I would get back “1332”.
I have looked at the examples on this and other forums but failed to get any to work for me.
BTW I note that I *could* loop through the children in the ‘results’ but looping seems inefficient so I’m hoping to use a more efficient method.

Comment: You're right that looping isn't necessarily the most efficient approach, but it should be fine for a relatively limited number of entries if it's not in a tight loop.  The only way to get more efficiency will be to build an index collection (if you deserialized to a dictionary, I think your natural key would be the id, so you'd still need to iterate to search on the make), which will have an up-front cost of iterating the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create an Object representing your Json  (copy your json to clipboard, in Visual Studio create an empty class and paste it as json classes Edit -> Paste Spacial -> paste json as class - I have a german VS, so maybe the menu is named differently)
2. Deserialize the json string in a new instance of this class
3. do your filtering as you need

I made a sample app for you on [GitHub](https://github.com/dbalogh78/JsonSample)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately the link to your sample on Github is not working.

Comment: Sorry, was set to private. Try again :-)

Comment: Thanks for updating that. I now have your sample which works a treat - many thanks. Unfortunately when I replicate the code in my project I'm getting an error:

This line gives the error "'jsonString' is not a member of 'System.Data'." 
         Dim cars = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Cars)(Data.jsonString)

Comment: I wondered whether it may be to do with a missing library reference, but to my un-trained eye I appear to have the right references.

Comment: Nope, the class name is a bit 'unlucky' since it may conflict with `System.Data` anyway, it's just a placeholder for json-string provider. I guess, you will read a file or so.. so just change the argument in the deserialize and drop "my" Data-class